# Using Commandline Arguments in Netbeans IDE 8.1

Tags: java, netbeans, command-line-arguments

I am trying to get my Java program to work but it gives me this error:

```
run:
Can't find file scores.txt
java.io.FileNotFoundException: scores.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
usage: java ScoresReader sourceFile destFile
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:611)
at Scores.project.ScoresReader.readData(ScoresReader.java:65)
at Scores.scoresreader.ScoresReader.main(ScoresReader.java:260)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type:
    cern.list.IntArrayList
at Scores.scoreseader.ScoresReader.main(ScoresReader.java:262)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

So from the 2nd line it says it can't find the file scores.txt even though I placed that file in the same directory as the class file (ScoresReader.java).

I also set the file scores.txt and dest.txt in the Netbeans 8.1 IDE configuration box according to the instructions given by the following:

```
1. Right click the project name and choose Set Configuration | Customize ...
2. In the configuration dialog, I typed the two files: scores.txt dest.txt
in the arguments box. And the two files showed up in the IDE o.k. Nothing
seem to be wrong there.
```

When I ran the project or file it gave me the above error. Here is an abbreviated code snippet:

```
public class ScoresReader implements Serializable
   {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7526472295622776147L;
    public OpenIntIntHashMap Scores;

    /**
    * Default constructor. Initializes hashtables. 
    */
    public ScoresReader()
       {
        Scores = new OpenIntIntHashMap();
        ..
        ..
       }
    /**
    * Reads a text file
    */
    public void readData(String fileName)
       {
        //Reads from an input text file in the form of:
        //score_id, user_id, score
        //and stores this data in the hashtables. 
       }

    /**
    * Serializes a ScoresReader object so that it can be read back later. 
    */
    public static void serialize(String fileName, ScoresReader obj)
       {
        //serialize the score objects
        ..
       }

    public static void main(String args[])
       {
        ScoresReader reader = new ScoresReader();
        String sourceFile = null;
        String destFile = null;
        try
           {
            sourceFile = args[0];
            destFile = args[1];
            reader.readData(sourceFile);
            reader.sortScores();
            serialize(destFile, reader);
             ..
             ..
           }
       catch(Exception e)
           {
            System.out.println("usage: java ScoresReader sourceFile destFile");
            e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }//end main
    }//end class ScoresReader
```

Can anyone please tell me why it can't find the file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In Netbeans, are you using the default package for storing the class file. In that case storing the stores.txt in same file is fine. If your class file is in 'src' folder, then the  txt file should be one folder above , ie in ../src

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Yes, I am using the default package and my class file, including other anciliary files all in the default package. What do mean the txt file should be one folder above? I looked in IDE and above the src folder is the project folder -- is that what you mean? Put the txt file in the project folder? Thanks!

Comment: O.K--putting the txt file one folder above the src folder seem to get rid of the "can't find file" error. But it gives me a different error and it is:  (See below)

Comment: run:
    usage: java ScoresReader sourceFile destFile
   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "# A test score file for ProjectScore GUI"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
 at java.lang.Short.parseShort(Short.java:118)
 at java.lang.Short.parseShort(Short.java:144)
 atProjectScore.scoresreader.ScoresReader.readData(ScoresReader.java:77)
 at ProjectScores.scoresreader.ScoresReader.main(ScoresReader.java:260)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: I would recommend a quick tutorial for reading objects from files http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-an-object-from-file-in-java/

Comment: Yeb--my code has all the necessary syntax of creating serialized objects and reading it back (deserialize). So that portion of the code is fine in my opinion.

Comment: I finally figured out the error message above and solved my problem. So to help others who encounter the same problem as I had, here is how solved it:

Comment: The note is error exception Java spits out: "java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "# A test score file for ProjectScore GUI". Java is telling me that my input file contains a string when it expects an integer for the input. The variable to accept input from a file was declared as an integer and not as string and that's why it gives out error because it expects an integer as an input from the file. I hope it helps others also.

Answer (score -1):

1. Open the "file" menu from the menubar
2. Select project properties
3. Go to the "run" tab
4. Insert the required arguments in the "arguments" field
5. Run the project normally by pressing "run"

This information comes from ["Netbeans IDE Blog by Tushar Joshi, Nagpur: Using Command Line Arguments in NetBeans IDE"](http://netbeanside61.blogspot.in/2009/02/using-command-line-arguments-in.html)